# Generic LinkedList with add/exists/delete/dlear/iteration functionality

Tags: c#, algorithm, linked-list

I've just been going through core data structures and algorithms recently, wanting to get back in touch with the core fundamentals. I'm starting simple with a `LinkedList` implementation in C#. The functionality works and was able to test it. I'm just wondering if yo see anything with the code that could be improved.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataStructuresAndAlgorithms.DataStructures.LinkedList
{
    public class SinglyLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public SinglyLinkedListNode<T> Head { get; set; }
        public SinglyLinkedListNode<T> Tail { get; set; }

        public void AddToEnd(T value)
        {
            var newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>
            {
                Value = value,
                Next = null
            };
            if (Head == null && Tail == null)
            {
                Head = newNode;
                Tail = newNode;
            }
            if (Head == Tail)
            {
                Head.Next = newNode;
                Tail = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                var existingLast = Tail;
                existingLast.Next = newNode;
                Tail = newNode;
            }
        }

        public void AddToBeginning(T value)
        {
            var newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>
            {
                Value = value,
                Next = null
            };
            if (Head == null && Tail == null)
            {
                Head = newNode;
                Tail = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                var existingHead = Head;
                Head = newNode;
                Head.Next = existingHead;
            }
        }

        public bool Exists(T value)
        {
            var head = Head;
            while(head != null)
            {
                if (head.Value.Equals(value))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                head = head.Next;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void Delete(T value)
        {
            var head = Head;
            SinglyLinkedListNode<T> previous = null;
            while(head != null)
            {
                if (head.Value.Equals(value))
                {
                    if (previous == null)
                    {
                        Head = Head.Next;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        previous.Next = head.Next;
                    }
                }
                previous = head;
                head = head.Next;
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            Head = null;
            Tail = null;
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            var head = Head;
            while(head != null)
            {
                yield return head.Value;
                head = head.Next;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }

    public class SinglyLinkedListNode<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public SinglyLinkedListNode<T> Next { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I would implement `ICollection<T>` in addition to `IEnumerable<T>`. It should be easy and straightforward.
- Public setters of the `Head` and `Tail` properties will allow users of your class to corrupt the structure of linked list.
- Not sure if you need to expose `Head` and `Tail` as properties at all, as they are the only ones who expose the `SinglyLinkedListNode<T>` instances used internally.
- `AddToEnd` implementation can be simplified. The case of `Head == Tail` doesn't differ from `else` clause. So the method can be refactored as following (note that the non-null `Head` implies non-null `Tail`, this should be guaranteed by the design of your class):

  ```
  public void AddToEnd(T value)
  {
      var newNode = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>
      {
          Value = value,
          Next = null
      };

      if (Head == null)
      {
          Head = newNode;
      }
      else
      {
          Tail.Next = newNode;
      }

      Tail = newNode;
  }
  ```
- Similar refactorings can be applied to `AddToBeginning`. When you create a new node to be inserted at the beginning, its `Next` property will always refer to original `Head` node, whether it was `null` (list is empty) or actual node. Thus the method can be reduced to:

  ```
  public void AddToBeginning(T value)
  {
      Head = new SinglyLinkedListNode<T>
      {
          Value = value,
          Next = Head
      };

      if (Tail == null)
      {
          Tail = Head;
      }
  }
  ```
- `Delete` method has a bug - it will never assign null to `Tail`, even if all elements are deleted from the list.

Comment: Thank you! All good points. I started to catch the redundancy of some of the conditions in the Add methods once I looked through it a couple of times. Awesome catch on the Delete bug, I will correct that.